# SailsJS Cannot set property 'authenticated' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

This is an old project and was used sailsjs and passport js for this Login authentication. When I try to log in, it returns the user details in JSON format which is right but it would redirect back to login page. However, it also returns an error which is `TypeError: Cannot set property 'authenticated' of undefined` which was set to `boolean`.

AuthController.js

```
passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {

    if (err || !user) {
       return tryAgain(challenges);
    }

    req.login(user, function (err) {
       if (err) {
          return tryAgain(err);
       }

       req.session.authenticated = true;

       res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Login.ejs

```
<form role="form" action="/auth/local" method="post">
        <div id="usernameBox" class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="identifier" placeholder="Username or Email"/>
        </div>
        <div id="passwordBox" class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotPasswordBox" class="form-group" hidden>
          <input id="resetEmail" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotPasswordBox" class="form-group">
          <div id="forgotPasswordButton" class="btn btn-white block full-width m-b">Forgot Password?</div>
        </div>
        <div id="signinBox" class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <div id="submitResetBox" class="form-group" hidden>
          <button id="submitResetButton" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Reset Password</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

routes.js

```
'POST /api/locallogin': 'AuthController.localCallback',
'get /login': 'AuthController.login',
'get /logout': 'AuthController.logout',
'get /register': 'AuthController.register',
'get /register/user': 'UserController.createUser',
'get /register/user/:token': 'UserController.createUserFromInvite',
'post /register/user/:token': 'UserController.createUserCallback',

'post /auth/local': 'AuthController.callback',
'post /auth/local/register': 'AuthController.doRegister',
'post /auth/local/:action': 'AuthController.callback',

'get /auth/:provider': 'AuthController.provider',
'get /auth/:provider/callback': 'AuthController.callback',
'get /auth/:provider/:action': 'AuthController.callback',
```

policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {

  '*': ['passport', 'bearerAuth', 'sessionAuth'],

  'auth': {
    '*': ['passport']
  },
  UserController: {
    requestPasswordReset: true,
    passwordCancel: true,
    passwordReset: true,
    getPasswordReset: true,
    createUserFromInvite: true,
    createUserCallback: ['passport']
  },
  PaymentController: {
    token: true,
    webhook: true
  },
  NewReportController: {
    reportComplete: true,
    reportFailed: true
  },
  ClashTestController: {
    exportComplete: true,
    exportFailed: true
  }
};
```

I have tried doing some research on the issue but ends up changing `req.session.authenticated = true;` to if statement which is something like this:

```
req.login(user, function (err) {
   if (err) {
      return tryAgain(err);
   }

   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.redirect('/');
   }
});
```

It has the same result that would return the details based on user credentials inputted, `req.isAuthenticated()` returns to `true` but redirected back to login page. What should be the cause of this error? I am stuck on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need some more information. One thing - do you reach this method via posting a form? Via an ajax call? Two - your problem may lay outside these methods with whatever your app serves at `/` the root url. Do you have policies or routes set on this route?

Comment: @arbuthnott actually, I am a newbie on passport and sailsjs. I just keep on tracing them. About the form, yes. It is an ajax call. I will be updating the questions with the forms, routes, and policies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the code we can see, it looks like you are doing things right... using `req.isAuthenticated()` is correct with passport. And the `res.redirect('/')` should do what you want.

Here's my best guess as to why you are ending up back in your login page. In your policies you have the line:

```
'*': ['passport', 'bearerAuth', 'sessionAuth'],
```

Since there is no specific route applied to the root url `/`, those policies are applied. One of them is probably checking if the user is logged in, and finding (in error) that they are not, and redirecting the user to the login page.

You can test any of this by just adding `console.log`'s inside your policies before the redirects. Possibly, you are still trying to use `req.session.authenticated` somewhere that `req.isAuthenticated()` should be used.

Hope this is helpful, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some miss-configuration on the session adapter